# Re render the page in react (next js) using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, react-hooks

I am building a next js application and need user authentication for that. In the page.js file I am sending a function call to firebase/firebaseAuth.js file, where it authorizes and sends the data to page.js.

In the page.js, using the state to store the data and render it on the screen. What changes should be made to re-render when the state is updated?

Currently, I have implemented window.reload, but I know it is not the best practice. What is the solution?

page.js =>

```
  const [user, setUser]= useState(null)  

useEffect(()=> {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token")
    if (token){
      const getUser= async (token)=>{
        try{
          const data= firebaseAuth.decrypt(token)
          setUser(data)
        }catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
      getUser(token)
    }
    
  }, [])

  const signInHandle= async ()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    const data=await firebaseAuth.signInWithGithub()
    await firestore.addUser(data)
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

firebase/firebaseAuth.js =>

```
export const firebaseAuth= {

     signInWithGithub : async () => {
        try{
        const response= await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
                sessionStorage.setItem('Token', response.user.accessToken)
                // window.location.reload()
                return (response.user)
        } catch (err){
                alert('You are already loggedin')
     }},
        
    logout : async () => {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('Token')
        },

    decrypt : ( token )=> {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
            return decoded
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error decoding token:', error);
            alert("Somethig went wrong!!")
          }
    },
}
```

Comment: ...React components that depend on state will automatically re-render when that state changes...so what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I moved the useEffect code to the signinHandle function and removed the useEffect. Since, the authentication happens only at the initial sign in, it doesn't have to re-render again.

```
const signInHandle= async ()=>{
setLoading(true)
const data=await firebaseAuth.signInWithGithub()
await firestore.addUser(data)

const token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token")
if (token){
  const getUser= async (token)=>{
    try{
      const data= firebaseAuth.decrypt(token)
      setUser(data)
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  getUser(token)
}
setLoading(false)
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `user` as a dependency to your useEffect, so that useEffect runs again when `user` changes.

```
 const [user, setUser]= useState(null)  

 useEffect(()=> {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token")
    if (token){
      const getUser= async (token)=>{
        try{
          const data= firebaseAuth.decrypt(token)
          setUser(data)
        }catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
      getUser(token)
    }
    
  }, [user])
```

Comment: You usually don't want to make state that you modify in a `useEffect` a dependency  without at least a conditional check because it can lead to infinite rendering loops.